# Can an equation be shown to be valid through logic over an continuous range?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, propositional-calculus

I may be asking the impossible - but would appreciate it if someone else were to confirm this for me, rather than me just thinking this...

I have a black box function, $f(x)$ that I don't know exactly, other than it changes over an underspecification, $x$. I know that I can find examples of $f(x) > threshold$ for a range of $x$, and I can maximise and minimise $x$'s range such that I think I know all the points $x \in [a, b]$ such that $f(x) > threshold$. Unfortunately, $x$ is continuous and therefore testing every single $x$ is impossible. Is it possible to prove, or say with some confidence, that $f(x) > threshold$ is ALWAYS true (what I know to be called "valid")?

I believe that if I knew $f(x)$, I could show properties of the function (monotone, etc) that would allow me to make such a claim.

Or, perhaps (I dont know what this is called) there is a way to say "I am confident up to $Y$% that this is always true" after doing a certain number/level of (random?) tests within the $f(x)$ range. Again, for this, I wouldn't be sure how to compute $Y$ given the infinite number of possibilities for $x$.

Am I right that I need to know $f(x)$? Or are there any other logic arguments I'm missing please?

Many thanks for any ideas/pointers in the right direction...